# DataGridRow {DisconnectedItem}

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridrow

I have WPF DataGrid without start binding and collection of DataGridRow ( for pagination ).
When user click number - some rows from collection produce IEnumerable and apply to DataGrid.ItemSource.
It's working on first set of ItemSource. But when we add new row to collection and then apply IEnumerable with some rows to ItemSource - old rows will receive Item property with {{DisconnectedItem}} value.

```
public List<DataGridRow> Rows
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _rows; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        _rows.Clear();  

        foreach(var row in value)
        {
            _rows.Add(row);
        }
    } 
}

private readonly List<DataGridRow> _rows;

DataGrid = new DataGrid()
{
    RowHeight = _rowHeight,
    ColumnHeaderHeight = columnHeight,

    AutoGenerateColumns = false,
    CanUserAddRows = false,
    CanUserDeleteRows = false,
    CanUserReorderColumns = false,
    CanUserResizeColumns = true,
    CanUserResizeRows = false,
    CanUserSortColumns = false,
    HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column,

    Width = width,
    MaxWidth = width,
    Height = height,
    MaxHeight = height,

    SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Single,
    SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow,

    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled,
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled,

    ColumnHeaderStyle = HeaderStyle,
    CellStyle = CellStyle,
};

 public void Navigate(PaginationDirections direction, int pageNumber = -1)
 {
     if (_tableWidget.DataGrid == null || _tableWidget.Rows == null || !_tableWidget.Rows.Any())
     {
         return;
     }

     int displayedRowsCount = _currentPage * _rowsPerPage;
     int previousPage = (displayedRowsCount / _rowsPerPage) - 1;
     int nextPage = (displayedRowsCount / _rowsPerPage) - 1;

     _totalPages = _tableWidget.Rows.Count / _rowsPerPage + 1;
     _comboBox.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, _totalPages).ToList();
     _comboBox.IsEnabled = _totalPages > 1;
     _button.IsEnabled = _totalPages > 1;
     IEnumerable<DataGridRow> rowsToDisplay = Enumerable.Empty<DataGridRow>();
     
     switch (direction)
     {
         case PaginationDirections.Previous:
             {
                 if(_currentPage == 1)
                 {
                     break;
                 }

                 _currentPage--;

                 if (previousPage == 1)
                 {
                     rowsToDisplay = _tableWidget.Rows.Take(_rowsPerPage);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     rowsToDisplay = _tableWidget.Rows.Skip(displayedRowsCount - _rowsPerPage).Take(_rowsPerPage);
                 }

                 _tableWidget.DataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRow>(rowsToDisplay);
                 break;
             }
         case PaginationDirections.Next:
             {
                 if(_currentPage == _totalPages)
                 {
                     break;
                 }

                 _currentPage++;

                 rowsToDisplay = _tableWidget.Rows.Skip(displayedRowsCount).Take(_rowsPerPage);

                 _tableWidget.DataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRow>(rowsToDisplay);
                 break;
             }
         case PaginationDirections.GoTo: //first apply
             {
                 if(pageNumber < 1 || pageNumber > _totalPages)
                 {
                     break;
                 }

                 _currentPage = pageNumber;

                 int rowsCountToSkip = pageNumber * _rowsPerPage;

                 if (pageNumber == 1)
                 {
                     rowsToDisplay = _tableWidget.Rows.Take(_rowsPerPage);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     rowsToDisplay = _tableWidget.Rows.Skip(rowsCountToSkip - _rowsPerPage).Take(_rowsPerPage);
                 }

                 _tableWidget.DataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRow>(rowsToDisplay);
                 break;
             }
         case PaginationDirections.Self: //second apply with new row in _tableWidget.Rows
             {
                 int rowsCountToSkip = _currentPage * _rowsPerPage;

                 if (_currentPage == 1)
                 {
                     rowsToDisplay = _tableWidget.Rows.Take(_rowsPerPage);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     rowsToDisplay = _tableWidget.Rows.Skip(rowsCountToSkip - _rowsPerPage).Take(_rowsPerPage);
                 }

                 _tableWidget.DataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRow>(rowsToDisplay);
                 //after it - {{ItemDisconnected}} for each row's Item property except new row
                 break;
             }
         default:
             {
                 break;
             }
     }
}
```

I tried to use ObservableCollection, List. Clear ItemSource before applying new rows.
But always new rows has {{ItemDisconnected}}...
Why it happening and how i can fix that?

Comment: Looks like you're messing up the virtualization of the DataGrid because you are adding DataGridRow containers explicitly. Instead you must create data models. DataGrid will now manage it's item containers properly and create/remove/reuse the DataGridRow containers for you. In WPF you never create own containers (e.g. ListBoxItem etc) explicitly. You only assign s collection of data items to the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl.

Comment: Actually I'm assigning collection of data items to the itemsource...

Comment: So DataGridRow is not the .Net type? How about showing a minimal example that reproduces the issue? This way we can review your code properly. Those snippets don't help. Those snippets even lack their context.

Comment: I mean that i do DataGriD.ItemSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRow>()

Comment: Is DataGridRow a custom type or not?

Comment: No, it isn't custom type

Comment: That's why I was saying before you should not add UI containers to the ItemsSource explicitly. This will mess with the virtualization of the ItemsSource, what is the reason for encountering the disconnected placeholder item. Please read my first comment again and follow the suggestions to solve your issue.

Comment: I can't use models because i need to create/delete Controls in runtime. Maybe i can disable virtualization?

Comment: You add/remove models to/from the source collection to create/delete controls in runtime. Just use models and define DataTemplates: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Why would you want to disable virtualization. Better write proper code. Using DataTemplates is very simple. Handling models is by far easier than handling controls directly. WPF is designed to work on data models and not on controls. Controls are always generated using data models and associated DataTemplates.

Comment: How i cab define DataTemplate if i don't know what data i will receive? It's very very dynamic

Comment: If you have dynamic data sets then create a DataTable as data model and assign this to the ItemsSource. The DataGrid will auto generate columns by default. When the data changes you simply create a new DataTable.

Comment: But also i have ComboBoxes, Images , Buttons and difficult visuals in Columns. DataTable - not supporting it

Comment: How can you have such complex cells when you don't know the table structure in advance? I understood you have dynamic table structures like dynamic column counts because you said you are not able to template columns: *"How i cab define DataTemplate if i don't know what data i will receive? It's very very dynamic"*. But to create cells with buttons and dropdowns as you said, you have to create column templates, and to create those you need to know the table structure in advance. Do you know the column count, column headers and cell data type in advance?

Comment: Yes, i receiving data about Columns though API. Then trough API i receiving data for cells

Comment: I'm already find solution. Thanks.